# Como obter o IP do dispositivo Android para ser usado no Socket() em java?

Tags: java, android, socket

Estou tentando implementar uma comunicação ponto à ponto(dispositivo à dispositivo) e preciso obter o IP real do dispositivo server para então inserir no client mas não consigo.
Estou usando:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
Log.v("TAG", server.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
```

e me retorna apenas "::".

Answer (score 1):

Você precisará fazer uma requisição para um servidor externo para saber o IP. Algo como isto:

```
https://github.com/kost/external-ip
```

================

No caso de IP Wi-Fi:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Ligando no manifesto:

```
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```